# Gnome 3 empathy can`t get the menu toolbar to show

Tags: unity, gnome, empathy

I can`t get empathy to show me the menu toolbar in ubuntu 12.10 in Gnome. When I log in in Unity, I can see the toolbar on the top, but that is not much comfy to need to go to Unity whenever I want to tweak settings.

Thanks,

Viktor

Comment: Nevermind, I found that. One can click on 'empathy up there in gnome 3 as well. Oh dear, so much time lost on such a stupid thing :(

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: *The OP solved the problem and mentioned it in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266721/gnome-3-empathy-cant-get-the-menu-toolbar-to-show/266731#comment334088_266721).*

> One can click on 'empathy up there in gnome 3 as well.